# PYPI package uploaded but can't be pip installed or found

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I've made a python package, and it has been uploaded to PyPi successfully [here](https://pypi.org/project/scanforwebcams/1.0/)

However, it doesn't pop up when searching in Pypi and it can't be downloaded via pip install.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have uploaded an egg — an outdated and no longer used distribution format. You need to upload a source distribution and/or wheels. See https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ for the tutorial on packaging.